# Rails 'link_to' concatenating URL automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I have two Facebook Login buttons in different parts of my website.
The buttons are identicals but one is working fine and the other one not.

When I click on the broken button, a url is concatenated automatically, doesn't matter what is the value for  *url* param on the [link_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) function that renders the button.

The URL concatenated is  *auth/facebook*, that is where I should go when clicking the button, but I should have set it as the URL param on *link_to* and not the rails putting it automatically.

Fine button:

```
<%= link_to "Entrar com Facebook", url_for(root_url+'auth/facebook'), class: "btn btn-facebook btn-block apoiar", id: "facebook_btn" %>
```

Broken button:

```
<%= link_to "Cadastrar com Facebook",url_for(root_url+'auth/facebook'), class: "btn btn-facebook btn-block apoiar btn-lg", id: "facebook_btn" %>
```

If I left the *link_to* URL param empty It works fine, but this is not the way the [omniauth gem docs](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth#integrating-omniauth-into-your-application) tells me to do and the other button is working fine...

[image]

I'm using [facebook omniauth gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook).